# PHP Form Not working - Solution Required

Tags: php

i have 2 Form on Contact page 1 is working and another is not working.. here is code of 2nd form.

on Contact page i have this codes

```
<form action="MailHandler1.php" id="ContactForm" method="post">
                                    <div class="success"> Contact form submitted!<br>
                                    <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong> </div>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners First & Last Name</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="ownername" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners Street Address</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="streetaddress" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners City</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="city" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners  State</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="state" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners Zip Code</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="zip" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners Phone Number</span>
                                            <label class="phone">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="ownerphone" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Owners  Email</span>
                                            <label class="email">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="ownersemails"class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants First & Last Name</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="tenantname" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants Street Address</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="teaddress" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants City</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="tecity" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants  State</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="testate" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants Zip Code</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="tezip" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Tenants  Country</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="tecountry" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Date Lease Started</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="tedatestarted" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Monthly Rent Amount</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="temonthlyrent" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Rent Amount Due Now</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="terentamountduenow" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Late Fees Due Now </span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="latefeedue" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Date Last Paid</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text"id="tedatelastpaid" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Is The Property Gated? Code? </span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text"id="tegated" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="wrapper">
                                            <span>Any Deposits Collected?</span>
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <span class="bg"><input type="text" id="teanydeposite" class="input"></span>
                                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="btns">
                                        <a href="#" class="link1" data-type="reset">Clear</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="link11" id="SendNotice" data-type="submit">Send</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
```

Now on php i have this code:

```
<?php

$owner_email = "abc@gmail.com";
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["ownersemails"];
$subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["ownername"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['ownername']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p> Owners First & Last Name : ' . $_POST["ownername"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['streetaddress']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p> Owners Street Address : ' . $_POST['streetaddress'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['city']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>  Owners City  : ' . $_POST['city'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>  Owners State  : ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST['zip']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Owners Zip Code   : ' . $_POST['zip'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['ownerphone']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Owners Phone Number   : ' . $_POST['ownerphone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['ownersemails']!='nope'){     
    $messageBody .= '<p> Owners Email : ' . $_POST['ownersemails'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['tenantname']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Tenants First & Last Name   : ' . $_POST['tenantname'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['teaddress']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>  Tenants Street Address  : ' . $_POST['teaddress'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}


if($_POST['tecity']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Tenants City   : ' . $_POST['tecity'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['testate']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Tenants State   : ' . $_POST['testate'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['tezip']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Tenants Zip Code   : ' . $_POST['tezip'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['tecountry']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Tenants Country   : ' . $_POST['tecountry'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['tedatestarted']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Date Lease Started   : ' . $_POST['tedatestarted'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['temonthlyrent']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Monthly Rent Amount   : ' . $_POST['temonthlyrent'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['terentamountduenow']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Rent Amount Due Now   : ' . $_POST['terentamountduenow'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['latefeedue']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>   Late Fees Due Now   : ' . $_POST['latefeedue'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST['tedatelastpaid']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>    Date Last Paid    : ' . $_POST['tedatelastpaid'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['tegated']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>    Is The Property Gated? Code?    : ' . $_POST['tegated'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['teanydeposite']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>    Any Deposits Collected?   : ' . $_POST['teanydeposite'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}




/*  
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}
*/
if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{

    /* mail($owner_email, "Subject: $subject",  $messageBody, $headerjusts ); */

    if(!mail($ownersemails, $ownername, $streetaddress, $city, $state, $zip, $ownerphone, $ownersemails, $tenantname, $teaddress, $tecity, $testate, $tezip, $tecountry, $tedatestarted, $temonthlyrent, $terentamountduenow, $latefeedue, $tedatelastpaid, $tegated, $teanydeposite)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }  
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

?>

Can some one please check and tell me where i am making mistake.. its not giving any error.

Comment: which one is working and which one is not ?

Comment: Also paste form 1 code

Comment: Hello,

Form 1 on Left side is working on right side form is not working.

http://mumbairabarisamaj.com/HTML2/#!/Contacts

Comment: First get your html right.
Both forms have the same id, "ContactForm".

See validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmumbairabarisamaj.com%2FHTML2%2F%23!%2FContacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you validating  for input form data. Change submit  to submit button, then only this form is submitted, and change the key of 'id' to 'name' in .

In MailHandler1.php file, change the line "if (isset($_POST["ownerphone"]))" instead "if($_POST['ownername']!='nope')".
After changing this you will get values in '$messageBody' variable.